# Unable to run (Linux container) or create image (Windows container) a Gatsby React site (win binaries error, matching manifest error) through Docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile, gatsby

I have my website wrapped up and wanted to containerize it for experience as I've never used Docker before. It's built on Gatsby. I did a fresh install of Docker and am running into two issues:

If I try to create an image in a Linux container, it seems to work, but I can't actually run it. I get the following error: "Error in "/app/node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp/gatsby-node.js": 'win32-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'linuxmusl-x64' platform. Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp' directory and run 'npm install' on the 'linuxmusl-x64' platform."

I tried the above, uninstalling and reinstalling sharp in my project to no avail.I'm not even using sharp nor do I know what it is, though.

If I switch to Windows containers, I can't even create an image as I get the following:
"no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18363 in the manifest list entries"

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and my .dockerignore contains

```
node_modules
build
Dockerfile
Dockerfile.prod
.git
```

Things I've tried:

This tutorial > https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/ (Where I got the Dockerfile text)

This tutorial >https://www.robinwieruch.de/docker-create-react-app-development (And its Dockerfile at one point)

Changing the FROM for node: to 14.4.0, 14, with or without -alpine.

Uninstalling and re-installing sharp

Uninstalling sharp entirely and trying to run it that way (I still get the sharp error for some reason)

Reading the documentation. Which for whatever reason only tells you how to launch a default application (such as create-react-app) or one pulled from somewhere, but not how to do so for our own website.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze As in the command? For installation I'm doing 
docker build -t mywebsite . 
and for running I'm running 
docker run -dp 80:80 mywebsite